# Format String date to another string format using java

Tags: java, date, format

I want to format a from string date to another String date value. The date is show as "03/20/2014". I have to format it to "2014-03-20". Could you please give me sample codeing for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String source= new String("03/20/2014");
        SimpleDateFormat sdfinput = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat sdfoutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date inputdate=sdfinput.parse(source);
            String outputDate=sdfoutput.format(inputdate);
        System.out.println(outputDate);
    }
}
```